# Force mySQL to join a table(to do a unoptimized query, that i need)

Tags: mysql, sql-match-all

This is kinda weird. I have the next query:

```
SELECT * , GROUP_CONCAT( x.tag
SEPARATOR ',' ) AS tags
FROM tag AS t, tag AS x, tag_message_rel AS r, message m
INNER JOIN `user` AS u ON m.user_id = u.id
WHERE t.tag
IN (
'kikikiki', 'dsa'
)
AND m.id = r.message_id
AND t.id = r.tag_id
AND x.id = r.tag_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING COUNT( * ) >=2
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

As you can see i use t to join find the messages that i want, on the other side i use x to print the tags of a message. I i erase the line:

```
AND x.id = r.tag_id
```

I will get the messages that i want, but tags will have ALL the tags in the tags table separated by coma. If i leave the line there, i will only get those 2 tags. 
If i use explain i get:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  u   system  PRIMARY     NULL    NULL    NULL    1   Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  t   range   PRIMARY,tag     tag     252     NULL    2   Using where
1   SIMPLE  x   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   verse.t.id  1    
1   SIMPLE  r   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    180     Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  m   eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   verse.r.message_id  1   Using where
```

Now im no expert in this, but i think the problem is that it is refusing to re-join a table in the process of optimizing the query.

What do you think? Any quick fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to join to the `tag` table twice, but you really need to join to the `tag_message_rel` table twice, and from each of these to the respective row in the `tag` table.

Think of "table aliases" as referring to a *row in a table*, not the table itself.  That idea helped me to understand complex joins a lot better.

Here's how I'd write that query:

```
SELECT m.*, u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT x.tag) AS tags
FROM message m
 JOIN `user` u ON (u.id = m.user_id)
 JOIN tag_message_rel r1 ON (m.id = r1.message_id)
 JOIN tag t ON (t.id = r1.tag_id)
 JOIN tag_message_rel r2 ON (m.id = r2.message_id)
 JOIN tag x ON (x.id = r2.tag_id)
WHERE t.tag IN ('kikikiki', 'dsa')
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag) = 2
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

You should develop the habit of using `JOIN` syntax consistently.  Mixing `JOIN` and comma-style joins can cause some subtle problems.

Here's an alternative query, that pulls some of the joins into a non-correlated subquery, so you avoid a Cartesian product between `t` and `x`, and eliminate the `DISTINCT` modifiers in the group functions.

```
SELECT m.*, u.*, GROUP_CONCAT(x.tag) AS tags
FROM message m
 JOIN `user` u ON (u.id = m.user_id)
 JOIN tag_message_rel r ON (m.id = r.message_id)
 JOIN tag x ON (x.id = r.tag_id)
WHERE m.id = ANY (
    SELECT m2.id 
    FROM message m2 
     JOIN tag_message_rel r2 ON (m2.id = r2.message_id)
     JOIN tag t ON (t.id = r2.tag_id)
    WHERE t.tag IN ('kikikiki', 'dsa') 
    GROUP BY m2.id 
    HAVING COUNT(t.tag) = 2)
GROUP BY m.id
ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only get those two tags, because:

1. t.tag IN ('kikikiki', 'dsa').
   2  t.id IN (id-for-kikikiki, id-for-dsa)
2. t.id = r.tag_id
3. r.tag_id = x.id
4. Combining 3 & 4, t.id = x.id
5. Combining everything, x.tag IN ('kikikiki', 'dsa')

I think what you want is to join a second `tag_message_rel`. Join `t` to the first one; join `x` to the second one; join them both to `message`. Not completely sure this is what you want, as you didn't actually say...